# Remove element from JS injected HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why wouldn't this work?

```
$description = '<div class="description"><p>This is a <a href="#">test</a></p></div>';
$($description).find('a').parent()[0].remove();
$('body').append($description);
```

I'm injecting some HTML using append, but before that I want to check the HTML for a link and if it exists I want to delete it's parent (tends to be a paragraph).

This doesn't seem to be working? Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide targeted HTML structure example? And there is only one parent of element (the 1st parent) look at the object returned from parent().

Comment: The HTML is all generated via JS as above.

Comment: You are not saving the results in any variable, are you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Nope... just deleting it there and then?

Comment: Do u have to remove all the predecessors or just the immediate one?

Comment: So all you want to do is insert `<div class="description"></div>`?

Comment: @SunilHari Just the immediate one... the parent of the link only.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Fair point but no... the contents of the div is supplied via an API so I want to check it before I append it.

Comment: Very simple. You are injecting the original string. You can copy it and play with it all you want but none of that will modify the string itself

Comment: Are u certain that the structure will be same.Can u give the sample output you are expecting?

Comment: @charlietfl Good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't seem to be working? Any thoughts?

Remove `[0]` as `parent()` will give you a jquery element while `[0]` will give you plain DOM element which doesn't have `remove()` method.

Also, you need to store the reference of jquery element that you are going to manipulate.

```
var description = '<div class="description">Out of P<p>This is a <a href="#">test</a></p></div>';
var $description = $( description );
$description.find('a').parent().remove();
$( 'body' ).append( $description );
```

**Demo**

```js
var description = '<div class="description">Out of P<p>This is a <a href="#">test</a></p></div>';
var $description = $( description );
$description.find('a').parent().remove();
$( 'body' ).append( $description );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you checked the demo?

Comment: That's it! And @charlietfl mentioned this too. It was still injecting the original string.